# .git folder gets locked

Tags: finder, permission, git

I'm on a M1 Mac mini. Randomly during the day, I can't commit my work because `git` is unable to create the `.git/index.lock` file. In the Finder info the folder shows up as "Locked". I unlocked it yesterday and got the same thing today. I ran the disk first aid and permission utility and also `xattr` and `chown` to remove any metadata. Tried pulling a fresh repo, didn't help. And it seems to be just this one repo, other folders are not affected. Any idea what's going on here?